# zebra printer GC420t dont print good

Tags: c#, .net, printing, zebra-printers, thermal-printer

I need to be able to use a zebra printer, the model is as follows: GC420t.
Install the following driver: ZDesigner GC420.
Search the internet for multiple solutions but for the moment none has worked for me.
For example one is the following:

```
  public static class RawPrinterHelper   {
        // Structure and API declarions:
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDataType;
        }
        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

        // SendBytesToPrinter()
        // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
        // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
        // Returns true on success, false on failure.
        public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
        {
            Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

            di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
            di.pDataType = "RAW";

            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write your bytes.
                        bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
            // about why not.
            if (bSuccess == false)
            {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return bSuccess;
        }
        public static bool SendMemoryToPrinter(string szPrinterName, MemoryStream ms)
        {            
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms);
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[ms.Length];
            bool bSuccess = false;
            IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
            int nLength;

            nLength = Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length);
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
            pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
            return bSuccess;
        }
        public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
        {
            // Open the file.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
            // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
            bool bSuccess = false;
            // Your unmanaged pointer.
            IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
            int nLength;

            nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
            // Read the contents of the file into the array.
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
            // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
            pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
            // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
            bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
            return bSuccess;
        }
        public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
        {
            IntPtr pBytes;
            Int32 dwCount;
            // How many characters are in the string?
            dwCount = szString.Length;
            // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
            // the string to ANSI text.
            pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
            // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
            SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I call this with this code:

```
string sampleText = "EXAMPLE LINE";
ZPLFont font = new ZPLFont(fontWidth: 20, fontHeight: 20);
var labelElements = new List<ZPLElementBase>();
labelElements.Add(new ZPLTextField(sampleText, 50, 10, font,ZPLTextField.NewLineConversionMethod.ToSpace,true,true));
labelElements.Add(new ZPLTextField(sampleText, 50, 30, font));
labelElements.Add(new ZPLTextField(sampleText, 50, 50, font));
labelElements.Add(new ZPLTextField(sampleText, 50, 70, font));
labelElements.Add(new ZPLTextField(sampleText, 50, 90, font));
labelElements.Add(new ZPLTextField(sampleText, 50, 110, font));
labelElements.Add(new ZPLTextField(sampleText, 50, 130, font));
labelElements.Add(new ZPLTextField(sampleText, 50, 150, font));
labelElements.Add(new ZPLTextField(sampleText, 50, 170, font));

var renderEngine = new ZPLEngine(labelElements);
var output = renderEngine.ToZPLString(new ZPLRenderOptions() { AddEmptyLineBeforeElementStart = true });

Debug.WriteLine(output);    

//RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(config.ConfigPrinter.PrinterName, output);
```

I use this dll to generate de ZPL code to send the printer: ZPLUtility

The code than generate the dll is the follow:

http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4.9&height=2.5&units=cm&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5ELH0%2C0%0A%5ECI28%0A%0A%5EA0N%2C20%2C20%0A%5EFO50%2C10%0A%5EFH%5EFR%5EFDEXAMPLE%20LINE%5EFS%0A%0A%5EA0N%2C20%2C20%0A%5EFO50%2C30%0A%5EFH%5EFDEXAMPLE%20LINE%5EFS%0A%0A%5EA0N%2C20%2C20%0A%5EFO50%2C50%0A%5EFH%5EFDEXAMPLE%20LINE%5EFS%0A%0A%5EA0N%2C20%2C20%0A%5EFO50%2C70%0A%5EFH%5EFDEXAMPLE%20LINE%5EFS%0A%0A%5EA0N%2C20%2C20%0A%5EFO50%2C90%0A%5EFH%5EFDEXAMPLE%20LINE%5EFS%0A%0A%5EA0N%2C20%2C20%0A%5EFO50%2C110%0A%5EFH%5EFDEXAMPLE%20LINE%5EFS%0A%0A%5EA0N%2C20%2C20%0A%5EFO50%2C130%0A%5EFH%5EFDEXAMPLE%20LINE%5EFS%0A%0A%5EA0N%2C20%2C20%0A%5EFO50%2C150%0A%5EFH%5EFDEXAMPLE%20LINE%5EFS%0A%0A%5EA0N%2C20%2C20%0A%5EFO50%2C170%0A%5EFH%5EFDEXAMPLE%20LINE%5EFS%0A%5EXZ

When I try to print the text does not appear as it appears on the screen, strange characters appear, I guess it will be something of encoding or the driver to translate the message.

Could someone run the printer from .net?

Thank you

Comment: Did you get the printer working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install your Zebra printer as Generic / Text only for ZPL to work.

https://km.zebra.com/resources/sites/ZEBRA/content/live/WHITE_PAPERS/0/WH70/en_US/UsingGenericPrinterDriverWindows7_WH.pdf

Comment: yes. I use one library to the nuget to translate the lenguage ZPL.